# Reading a specific portion of data from a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>gene1
ATGATGATGGCG
>gene2
GGCATATC
CGGATACC
>gene3
TAGCTAGCCCGC
```

This is the text file which I am trying to read.
I want to read every gene in a different string and then add it in a list
There are header lines starting with  ’>’ character to recognize if this is a start or end of a gene

```
with open('sequences1.txt') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
            while line != ">":
                list.append(line)
    print(list)
```

When printed the list should display list should be

```
list =["ATGATGATGGCG","GGCATATCCGGATACC","TAGCTAGCCCGC"]
```

Comment: `list.append(line)` is illegal

Comment: @Swaraj Added an answer already, kindly check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('sequences1.txt') as input_data:
    sequences = []
    gene = []
    for line in input_data:
        if line.startswith('>gene'):
            if gene:
                sequences.append(''.join(gene))
                gene = []
        else:
            gene.append(line.strip())
sequences.append(''.join(gene)) # append last gene
print(sequences)
```

output:

```
['ATGATGATGGCG', 'GGCATATCCGGATACC', 'TAGCTAGCCCGC']
```

Comment: Only answer to combine the multiple genes as desired by OP (so far).

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

sequences1.txt:

```
>gene1
ATGATGATGGCG
>gene2
GGCATATC
CGGATACC
>gene3
TAGCTAGCCCGC
```

and then:

```
desired_text = []
with open('sequences1.txt') as input_data:
    content = input_data.readlines()
    content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
    for line in content:
            if not line.startswith('>'):
                desired_text.append(line)

print(desired_text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['ATGATGATGGCG', 'GGCATATC', 'CGGATACC', 'TAGCTAGCCCGC']
```

**EDIT:**

Sped-read it, fixed it with the desired output

```
with open('sequences1.txt') as input_data:
    content = input_data.readlines()
    # you may also want to remove empty lines
    content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
    # flag
    nextLine = False
    # list to save the lines
    textList = []
    concatenated = ''
    for line in content:
        find_TC = line.find('gene')

        if find_TC > 0:
            nextLine = not nextLine
        else:
            if nextLine:
                textList.append(line)
            else:
                if find_TC < 0:
                    if concatenated != '':
                        concatenated = concatenated + line
                        textList.append(concatenated)
                    else:
                        concatenated = line

print(textList)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['ATGATGATGGCG', 'GGCATATCCGGATACC', 'TAGCTAGCCCGC']
```

Comment: Don't read everything in advance. What's wrong with `for line in input_data:` ?

Comment: OP wants lines concatenated if next line is not `">gene#"`

Comment: For gene2 it is getting 2 different string but what it should really do is that it should concatenate it

Comment: @Swaraj my bad, I misinterpreted at first,  fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mistakes in your code, look here:

```
with open('sequences1.txt', 'r') as file:
    list = []
    for line in file.read().split('\n'):
            if not line.startswith(">") and len(line$
                list.append(line)
    print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ cat genes.txt
>gene1
ATGATGATGGCG
>gene2
GGCATATC
CGGATACC
>gene3
TAGCTAGCCCGC


$ python
>>> genes = []
>>> with open('genes.txt') as file_:
...   for line in f:
...     if not line.startswith('>'):
...       genes.append(line.strip())
...
>>> print(genes)
['ATGATGATGGCG', 'GGCATATC', 'CGGATACC', 'TAGCTAGCCCGC']
```